# How to reference a cell using a cell value?

Tags: google-sheets

I'm sure this is not as complicated as I'm trying to make it. What I'm trying to do is take a calculated cell value, add a letter to it, and reference it from another sheet.

So, if A1 is a value of 1, then I want the value of Sheet1!A1
If A1 is 92, I want the value of Sheet1!A92
If A1 is 0, I don't want anything.
If A1 is blank, I don't want anything.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully if you are here, you had a similar question. Well, I've solved it and I'd love to share the solution with you.

```
=Indirect("A" & A1)
```

That's it!

Now for more detail... I was trying to import data from a website that insisted on using multiple columns for no good reason. So if you have that issue, and need to pull data for multiple users with exactly similar importdata structures, you'll want to do it side by side. Usually you'll order users from top down, but when you importdata, it leaves a huge dump vertically. Transpose is the answer here... kinda. Transpose doesn't allow for spacing between columns. So what I had to do was automatically generate cell references every 7 spaces. This is just enough room for every user to be able to have their own space for a huge data dump. Then you just search the first row for the user name, use that column and a predetermined row to find the exact value you were searching for to begin with deep in the data dump. bring that back to your original sheet, and use a lot of unnecessarily complex formulas to pull it.

If anyone can make this process easier, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: I likely have answers for you but need some more detail like data your trying to pull.and ideal result.  A sample sheet would be best